# XSS filter - hash sign in response from IE

Tags: security, internet-explorer, xss

I am testing an application for reflected cross-site scripting.
I have urls which were originally a problem and were fixed by encoding various elements in the application's response. I am trying to make sure there are no other loopholes.
The scenario is as follows:
I try a few URLs containing XSS in them and they are fine in IE.
Then I try a url which I know is still vulnerable and I get the IE xss blocking warning with my page content slightly modified (which is what i expect).
Then I try again one of the above urls which were fine, and suddenly IE replaces the **entire** content of the page with a `#` sign and displays the XSS alert. so I can't even see the response.
After testing a few times I have a theory that after trying a vulnerable url and trying a similar one which isn't supposed to be vulnerable (the response is modified on the server side) IE for some reason blocks the entire page.
In the official docs of the XSS filter this isn't mentioned.

In what situation does IE replace the entire response with a `#` rather than modifying the response only in the vulnerable location?

Comment: What happens with other browsers?

Comment: Well the xss I am testing is specific for IE (like using expr/**/ssion in style attribute) so other browsers are fine.

Comment: I'll narrow down the question maybe: In what situation does IE replace the entire response with a "#" rather they modifying the response only in the vulnerable location?

Comment: Hi, We are having similar issue.Did you find any solutions for this?

Comment: I didn't find a solution, but I think IE may be checking the request and since it identifies and XSS vulnerability it blocks the page (and doesn't wait to see what the response looks like.